# Finding website name for a given string using python

Tags: python

I am new to python world, I am wondering is there a way to find out the website name for a given string. The string could be place name or place of interest.

Thanks for quick reply, what I am trying to build a database of colleges for a given place. So far I got list of college names, now I would like to get their websites so that I can add to the database. For eg, if I search for standford in google I can the link to the college website. I tried using xpath for the first link to the search results, but sometime I noticed google displays ads and i cannot generalise this. So I am looking for some alternatives way to do this

Comment: Can you give us an example? What does the string look like? And what do you mean with "website" name?

Comment: What's your actual programming question? Are you saying some script should take "New York" for an input and return "www.applebeesny.com"? What's your I/O logic (in plain english)?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, what I am trying to build a database of colleges for a given place. So far I got list of college names, now I would like to get their websites so that I can add to the database. For eg, if I search for standford in google I can the link to the college website. I tried using xpath for the first link to the search results, but sometime I noticed google displays ads and i cannot generalise this. So I am looking for some alternatives way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like [Google Search API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/training/fts_intro/) and then use the first returned result.

Or do you want to do it without an API? That would be more difficult. You could probably use [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) to check if the website exists. But you would have to create the url from the string by yourself. Which gives you a lot of possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did try using the xpath to find the link for the first result in the google search results, unfortunately sometimes google displays link to some of the ads. So most of the time, it will not be the first returned result. Is there any way of finding it out.

Comment: since you are comfortable using Google. I would just use the Google Search API. [Here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/training/fts_intro/lesson2) are the basics described.
[Here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/indexclass#Index_search) is a description of the Index Class

Comment: thanks for giving me the information. I shall try making use of google searcg APIs.